# Flex: How to Call a Custom Component's Public Function in the Main App?

Tags: apache-flex, function, custom-component

How do I call a custom component's public function from the main app. For example, I've got a timer component, MyTimer.

In the main app, I want to call startTimer() or stopTimer().

In the main app, I've got:

```
<visualcomponent:MyTimer />
```

In the component, I've got:

```
public function startTimer():void {
     baseTimer = getTimer();
     t.start();
     }
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set an ID for your component so that the instance can be referenced:

```
<visualcomponent:MyTimer id="myTimer" />
```

Now you can say in your main app's script code:

```
myTimer.startTimer();
```

Comment: Hi thenduks, Sweet! Thank you for the help.

Comment: Hi Stefan, Thank you for helping me, too.